# How to clear all data from an app in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-manage.py

I want to remove all data from all models defined in a single Django app. The number of models might change in the app, hence I don't want to hard code model names. It would be great if it might be done using `manage.py` command, however I was not able to find one.

The `manage.py flush` command is not suitable, because it only allows to clear data from all apps.

Comment: what is your database provider... sql?? psql??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using django version greater than 1.7, which you are. You can simply use `migrate zero` command to drop from specific app. Like:

```
py manage.py migrate APPNAME zero
```

Here, APPNAME is name of the app from where you want to flush data.
[Refs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#reversing-migrations)

Comment: `manage.py migrate APPNAME zero` and then `manage.py migrate APPNAME` does the job. The tables of an app are dropped and recreated.